# Facebook Pages - how to retain the name

Tags: facebook

Currently I have a page attached to my personal Facebook profile.
I would first like to delete the page from my personal Facebook profile and start a fresh page for my business that is not linked to my personal Facebook profile.
I would like to make a business Facebook profile instead.

I do not want to lose the name that I currently have on my personal profile page.

My questions are:

1. Once I delete the Facebook page (I know how to do that), how long do I have to wait to use my page 'name' again?
2. If there is a waiting period - is there a chance they can release it sooner? I really do not want to lose my page name.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: What you mean by _page attached to my personal Facebook profile_? You are admin of that page, right? Or it is attached in any other way?

Comment: Yes I am the administrator of that page. I created it under my own profile.

Answer (score 1):

A Facebook page *is* itself a *business* *"profile"*.

Pages are only meant for public communication, be they with customers or fans (for public figures, such as artists etc.).

Also, you *need* a Facebook Profile ( which is your personal space on the platform) to setup a Page. I am not sure why you want to delete the Page and not  ***link it with your Profile .***

[The Official Facebook help on the topic](https://m.facebook.com/help/135275340210354/create-and-manage-a-page/?helpref=hc_fnav) might help.

If you want to make a *separate* Facebook Profile to use it for business purposes and link that with your Page ( I am guessing that's what you mean by a Facebook *business* Profile), it is against Facebook Community Standards to have ***two profiles***.

Ideally, they ask you to use one Personal Profile and link your businesses as Pages with the same profile.

Answer (score 0):

I would not delete the page. Instead just unlink your Facebook profile and Facebook page, and then change the category of your same old Facebook page.

So when you go into the About section of your Facebook page, your profile should be removed from that public Team Member list. After you have done this, your page should also have disappeared from the About section of your Facebook profile.

Just ask me, if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: Always add detailed answer, don't wait for OP to ask, because your answer is not just to help the OP, it is going to help future readers also.